# Using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of an http proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

When I put the http proxy behind nginx using `proxy_pass` directive, the http proxy receives a request like `GET /some/path` while it expects to receive a request like `GET http://some.domain/some/path`. How should I configure nginx to not omit the hostname passed URL? Note that only setting the `Host` header is not enough for the http proxy to function correctly.

Comment: nginx does not expect to need to do this. Use a forward proxy such as squid.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as Nginx developers said, Nginx is not forward proxy and doesn't need to be used this way